# Using $row["Name"] causes a quotation mark if there is a space between words

Tags: php, html

I wanted to make a table that has a function which is used when the particular table element is clicked. It uses the rows name for the function values. It works for things which only have a single word for their name (for example "Meal"), but its multiple words (for example "Homemade Chicken Noodle Soup") then it closes the value too early with a quotation mark that doesn't exist in the name. I want to know why that happens and if its possible to fix it.

**Inspect element for the broken html:**

```
<tr class="tr active" id="Homemade Chicken Noodle Soup" onclick="show("Homemade" chicken noodle soup")>
```

**Inspect element for the correct html:**

```
<tr class="tr" id="jelo" onclick="show("jelo")">
```

**Php code for the element:**

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Calories, Fat, SaturatedFat, TransFat, 
            Cholesterol, Salt, Carbohydrate, DiateryFiber,Sugar 
        FROM recepti";
$result =$db -> query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ...
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'
        <tr class="tr" id="'.$row["Name"].'" onclick=show("'.$row["Name"].'")>';
        ...
    }
    $db->close();
}
```

[**The broken row:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfkFg.png)

Comment: Look at the quote marks!! You cannot have a double quote inside a double quoted string. Use single quote inside a doublequoted string or concatenate information ito the string

Comment: ___id's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.)___ [From the HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)Manual

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you mean the row id cant contain spaces, the id for the tr, or the values inside functions?

Comment: the `id` attribute of any html element cannot contain spaces

Comment: Your `onclick="show("Homemade" chicken noodle soup")` is also wrong, although I dont see how that was generated from the code you show unless `$row['name']` contains a string with part of it already quoted like `"Homemade" chicken noodle soup`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with your quotation marks. HTML is very forgiving and it will try to make sense of an attribute even if the value is not enclosed in quotes. However, it will only consider the value until the next whitespace.

You have

```
onclick=show("'.$row["Name"].'")
```

Which I assume is then outputted as

```
onclick=show("Homemade chicken noodle soup"
//                    ^ This is the first whitespace
```

This is invalid HTML so HTML will try to guess what you meant. It has put quotation marks in the place where is the first whitespace; this was the most logical place according to HTML parsing rules. The rest of the string is treated as custom attributes and a rogue quotation mark in the end.

See how the inspector highlights it:
[image]

To fix the problem you have to enclose the `onclick` value in another pair of quotation marks. I used single quotation marks which I escaped in PHP.

```
echo'<tr class="tr" id="'.$row["Name"].'" onclick=\'show("'.$row["Name"].'")\' >';
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I didn't know you can use slash for setting quotation marks to be for the string.

Comment: @BottomCroat Slashes escape special characters in PHP strings. When you want a quotation to be treated literally by PHP then you need to escape it. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php